# Hostname shows up twice in reports but not request URI

Tags: google-analytics

I'm seeing the hostname twice on my GA reports, like this:

```
domain.comdomain.com
```

It's also happening on my view that only includes traffic from a single subdomain:

```
subdomain.domain.comsubdomain.domain.com
```

Request URI is not showing up in either view (it looks like everything is getting lumped together).

I'm using GTM to fire the tracking code in the root domain, and Unbounce's GA integration for the subdomain (it's our landing page subsite). The only thing I could think of is an error in our hostname prepend filter in both views, I'm using LunaMetric's recipe for prepending hostnames to request URI: https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/12/10/basic-google-analytics-filters/

But I double-checked and it's correct (at least, it matches the recipe). In our unfiltered view, everything shows up correctly (URI without hostname prepended). Other filters I'm using are ones that lowercase everything (hostname, campaign medium/source/name/etc., and an IP filter to strip out internal traffic).

Any ideas why this might be happening? I'm at a loss. Thanks!

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, this seems to be a problem with your filter (specifically it sounds like you are either extracting the hostname twice in your advanced filter, instead of having "hostname" for field A and "request Url" for Field B, or you are writing the extracted hostname twice to the output field ($A$A instead of $A$B). Maybe you can post a screenshot of your filter configuration to check this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @EikePierstorff Thanks, stupid question on my part - that was the issue.